# Assign dynamic options to select2 plugin constructor

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to dynamically create options for the select boxes on a page, using the select2 plugin.
Specifically I'm trying to only display the search box on elements that contain the 'search' class.

I've been playing with all sorts of syntax to dynamically insert the correct option and I'm almost there, but I can't quite seem to get it working in the way I need.

I have the following code:

```
    $('.select2')
    .select2({
        width: 'resolve'
        // Toggle search box with class
        ,   minimumResultsForSearch: function(){var searchOption = this.element.hasClass('search') ? 1 : -1; return searchOption}
    });
```

The code seems to work ok when applided to the 'width' option, thus:

```
    $('.select2')
    .select2({
        width: function(){var thisWidth = this.element.hasClass('long') ? 400 : 200; return thisWidth}
    });
```

However if I were to replace one of the options with 'resolve' instead of an integer, it doesn't take... and I can't in any way get it to work on the `minimumResultsForSearch` option.

I assume I'm doing something glaringly obviously incorrect... Can anyone steer me in the right direction?